# Como funcionan los VAOs en OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

He intentado buscar en montones de tutoriales y documentaciones en internet sobre los VAOs porque me cuestan mucho entenderlos, pero es que parece imposible.

Por lo que tengo entendido, se supone que si llamas a glBindVertexArray, a partir de ahi cuando llames al metodo glBindBuffer el buffer asociado se guardara en el VAO. De modo que si haces esto:

```
glBindVertexArray(VAOs[0]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOs[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(vertices),vertices,GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,2*sizeof(GLfloat),(void*)0);
```

Entonces a partir de aqui cada vez que hagas esto:
Código
glBindVertexArray(VAOs[0]);

Automaticamente seria como si estuvieras haciendo esto: (Aunque no lo "haces" porque ya esta hecho, solo restauras el buffer que ya esta "hecho")

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOs[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(vertices),vertices,GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,2*sizeof(GLfloat),(void*)0);
```

Pero cuando hago varios VAOs y a cada VAO le pongo un VBO, por alguna razon cuando pongo el primer, segundo o tercer VAO y compruebo cual es el VBO actual, se me queda en el ultimo VBO con el que llame al metodo glBindBuffer. ¿Por que? Yo digo algo asi:

```
glBindVertexArray(VAOs[0]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOs[0]);
glBindVertexArray(VAOs[1]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOs[1]);
glBindVertexArray(VAOs[2]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOs[2]);

glBindVertexArray(VAOs[0]);
GLint n;
glGetIntegerv(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING, &n);
std::cout << "VBO ACTUAL: " << n << std::endl;//Imprime VBOs[2] pero deberia imprimir VBOs[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL es una maquina de estados, esto quiere decir que para utilizar un objeto, en tu caso un VAO, primero debes activarlo, para activar un VAO usas la función **glBindVertexArray(vao_id)**, todas las operaciones que realices a partir de la activación del VAO se ejecutarán sobre dicho objeto, de modo que llamar a la función **glGetIntegerv(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING, &n)** te devolverá el ID del VAO que está activo, en tu caso el último, cuando termines de utilizarlo puedes desactivarlo con **glBindVertexArray(0)**.

Puedes ver más tutoriales en: http://acodigo.blogspot.com/p/opengl.html

```
GLuint VAOs[3], VBOs[3];

glGenVertexArrays(3, VAOs);
glGenBuffers(3, VBOs);

glBindVertexArray(VAOs[0]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOs[0]);
glBindVertexArray(0);

glBindVertexArray(VAOs[1]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOs[1]);
glBindVertexArray(0);

glBindVertexArray(VAOs[2]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOs[2]);
glBindVertexArray(0);

glBindVertexArray(VAOs[2]);

GLint n;
glGetIntegerv(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING, &n);
std::cout << "VBO ACTUAL: " << n << std::endl;
```